# How to build a list of subelements from list of dictionaries in Ansible

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

Please help me to build a list of subelements from a list of dictionaries using one line filter

```
vars:
  source_list:
      - { name: 'name1', addr: 'ip1' }
      - { name: 'name2', addr: 'ip2' }
      - { name: 'name3', addr: 'ip3' }
  dest_list: "{{ source_list | XXXXXX }}"
```

`debug: var=dest_list` output should look like this

```
[ 'ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3' ]
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `map(attribute='addr')`, this will extract the values of the specified attribute from a list of dicts.

The task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ dest_list }}"
  vars:
    source_list:
        - { name: 'name1', addr: 'ip1' }
        - { name: 'name2', addr: 'ip2' }
        - { name: 'name3', addr: 'ip3' }
    dest_list: "{{ source_list | map(attribute='addr') }}"
```

Returns the following result:

```
TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "ip1",
        "ip2",
        "ip3"
    ]
}
```